# Gulp + RequireJS Remove Vendor Files

Tags: requirejs, gulp

I'm having a problem using Gulp to compile a RequireJS project properly. What I need to do is have gulp create a single distribution file that only includes the file necessary to have the application run.

In our application we are following a modular approach breaking out major pieces of functionality into different repos. So while developing my piece I have RequireJS including angular and many other vendor libraries that are common to all of the projects in the application. However when I go to move my piece into the larger application I no longer need these files in the final output since those dependencies also exist in that application (and having those extra libraries also makes the final distribution file over 300K).

I've tried creating another main.js (called gulp-main.js) file that only includes the dependencies that I need but when I run the gulp process it fails. I don't get an error but it seems to be failing because I'm not including the required dependencies for the project to build successfully. Below is the config object that is being passed to the RequireJS optimize method.

```
var config = {
    baseUrl: 'app/',
    mainConfigFile: 'app/main.js',
    out: 'dist/app/output.js',
    name: 'main'
};
```

Any ideas on what I could do to either remove the unnecessary vendor files or even split them into a single vendor and a single non-vendor file would really be appreciated. I have already tried using the modules array option but that does not produce the results that I am after since it seems to create a single file for each item defined not a single compiled JS file with all scripts contained within.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't want some file in your final output. add `" ! "` in Your gulp task's src

example :

```
 gulp.src(['./app/*.js', '!./node_modules/**'])    // '!./vendor-libraries-dest to igonore'
```

Comment: This works when using gulp.src but I'm trying to change the output of the call to requirejs.optimize. When I run that it goes through my require main file and produces a library with all of my files that require needs to run the file as a stand alone application. I have seen examples using amdOptimize but it still looks like it has the same problem.